# JS loaded from template won't run inside custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, jquery, javascript

I created a module position at my template where I load a custom module which is a menu bar.

with the next script I change its position to `fixed` if someone scrolls more than `200px` so that the bar will always be on top.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  var jQueryel = jQuery('.fixedElement'); 
  var isPositionFixed = (jQueryel.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
    jQuery('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    jQuery('.fixedElement').addClass("bgNormal");

  }
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed)
  {
    jQuery('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px'}); 
    jQuery('.fixedElement').removeClass("bgNormal");
  } 
});
```

I added this script inside the head of template. It runs smoothly in every page except of the `views` of a custom `component` I made.

Console doesn't output any error and inspecting the source code I can find that the script is loaded correctly.
For some reason it just wont run.

`jQuery` is correctly loaded and I cant think of anything that would affect the view to run the js.

I uploaded another `component` and I found that it wouldn't run the script either.

Is this a common issue ? Do I have to do something in order to load scripts from template to view ? Or it's a development problem ?

Comment: Is this a common issue? Do I have to do something in order to load scripts from template to view? - Not a common issue - and it doesn't require anything special, by the moment has been attached successfully to the document. So my guess is that it is something with the js itself in relation with the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after alot of searching i find out that this was a mainly css issue.

`$(window).scroll()` wouldn't trigger because the `#content div` was getting a random rule that wouldn't let it `overflow`.

So `$(window)` wouldn't scroll no matter what.

Fixing that, made it work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For some custom components I found I had to add a "wrapper" feature to the js in the views to get them to work correctly.

Since you are only having trouble with the script in the custom components section it may be a conflict in the way the component is loading scripts, as opposed to the way Joomla core handles scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
                var jQueryel = jQuery('.fixedElement'); 
                var isPositionFixed = (jQueryel.css('position') == 'fixed');
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
                    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
                    $('.fixedElement').addClass("bgNormal");

                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed)
                {
                    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px'}); 
                    $('.fixedElement').removeClass("bgNormal");
                } 
            });
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: this is throwing an error "expecting expression"